# Euclidean Operator Norm Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $||A||=\sqrt{||AA^T||}$ where $||A||$ is the euclidean operator norm. I'm thinking something along the lines of inner products and making use of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Hello there! First of all, please include all relevant details in your question as well as your own efforts to solve this question!  
In your case, you probably want to proof that the Matrix norm for real valued matrices induced by the euclidean norm $||.||_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $||A||_2=\sup_{||x||_2=1} ||Ax||_2=\sqrt{\lambda_max(A^T A)} $, where $\lambda_max$ denotes the biggest eigenvalue.  
I do not know for sure if this is the case, but please edit your question to include any helpful details as well as your own attempt to solve the problem!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is an inequality, used to prove inequalities, not equalities.

Comment: @abolfazl: that''s a bold statement. The standard proof to the above equality, which I wrote below, uses Cauchy-Schwarz as the OP says.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, using Cauchy-Schwarz, that $$\tag1\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle\leq\|A^*A\|\,\|x\|^2=\|A^*A\|.$$ Then 
$$\tag2
\|A\|^2=\sup\{\|Ax\|^2:\ \|x\|=1\}
=\sup\{\langle Ax,Ax\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\leq\|A^*A\|.
$$
Conversely,
$$\tag3
\|A^*A\|\leq\|A\|\,\|A^*\|.
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, you get
$$
\|A\|^2\leq\|A\|\,\|A^*\|,
$$
implying $\|A\|\leq\|A\|^*$. If we repeat the above for $A^*$ we get $\|A^*\|\leq\|A^{**}\|=\|A\|$, so $\|A^*\|=\|A\|$.

Now we go back to $(3)$ to get
$$\tag4
\|A^*A\|\leq\|A\|^2,
$$
and $(2)$ and $(4)$ give 
$\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2$.